# Expanding Link Abbreviatons, Dreamweaver Setting

Tags: html, settings, dreamweaver

I think this is a pretty basic question, but I just haven't been able to find a solution for this through google.

In Dreamweaver, in the code view, Dreamweaver will oftentimes abbreviate links and src's in order to make the experience more aesthetic and the code more easily browseable. However, I wanted to know how to disable this feature.

For example, currently, I have instances where it is: 
 
or

```
<script src="../Blog/js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Blog/js/jquery.cubeportfolio.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Blog/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I do not want the ".." or the "../..", I want to see the whole directory process as much as it is possible.

Is it possible to stop having Adobe Dreamweaver do that and how would I go about doing that?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the nature of using Dev environments.  The simple answer is, Dreamweaver uses relative paths so you can develop without having to change paths manually when you upload.  ../ means one folder above your html file. Makes it easier to develop.  Answer according to Adobe forums is you can't.  This might help:
https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/paths-dreamweaver-templates.html